# time.Sub() returns 1 second despite the difference exceeding couple of years

Tags: go, time, difference

I am trying to write a piece of code that will react to system time change due to synchronisation. Here's a rather simple code that is running inside of goroutine:

```
var start, end time.Time
var start_ts, end_ts int64
var diff_ts time.Duration
var diff time.Duration

for {
    start = time.Now()
    start_ts = start.Unix()
    fmt.Printf("Now: => %v (%d);\n", start, start_ts)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    end = time.Now()
    end_ts = end.Unix()
    fmt.Printf("New Now: %v (%d);\n", end, end_ts)
    diff = end.Sub(start)
    diff_ts = time.Duration(end_ts-start_ts) * time.Second
    fmt.Printf("Measured time duration: %v (%v) %f (%f)\n", diff, diff_ts, diff.Seconds(), diff_ts.Seconds())
}
```

my problem is that when I change system time in another console, the time is read correctly, however the "original" time difference is incorrect and I have to resort to constructing the time difference manually. Here's the excerpt from the logs:

```
Now: => 2020-02-26 12:29:42.778827718 +0000 UTC m=+21.776791756 (1582720182);
New Now: 2017-01-01 01:02:03.391215325 +0000 UTC m=+22.777003266 (1483232523);
Measured time duration: 1.00021151s (-27635h27m39s) 1.000212 (-99487659.000000)
```

how come the diff object returns 1 second even though the difference is clearlly greater than that?

Comment: Your expected behavior is considered a bug, and [Go fixed it in 1.9](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#monotonic-time) in response to [this problem](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-and-why-the-leap-second-affected-cloudflare-dns/).

Comment: Note that you can strip the monotonic clock reading from a time value. Two times that *lack* monotonic clocks can be subtracted, giving the clock-face-value difference, instead of the monotonic-clock difference: *Because t.AddDate(y, m, d), t.Round(d), and t.Truncate(d) are wall time computations, they always strip any monotonic clock reading from their results.* (time package documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go's time package uses both "wall clock" (what you are trying to change) and a monotonic clock. From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/):

> Operating systems provide both a “wall clock,” which is subject to
>   changes for clock synchronization, and a “monotonic clock,” which is
>   not. The general rule is that the wall clock is for telling time and
>   the monotonic clock is for measuring time. Rather than split the API,
>   in this package the Time returned by time.Now contains both a wall
>   clock reading and a monotonic clock reading; later time-telling
>   operations use the wall clock reading, but later time-measuring
>   operations, specifically comparisons and subtractions, use the
>   monotonic clock reading.
>
> [...]
>
> If Times t and u both contain monotonic clock readings, the operations t.After(u), t.Before(u), t.Equal(u), and t.Sub(u) are carried out using the monotonic clock readings alone, ignoring the wall clock readings.

This is specifically designed to prevent deviant app behavior when a clock-sync (ntp etc.) occurs (and pushes the clock back). go's time package ensures the monotonic clock reading always moves forward (when comparing or subtraction operations).

Comment: So to essentially answer your question, your app does not need to worry about host OS time changes. Log timestamps may move backwards after a sync (i.e. time _telling_) but time _calculations_ are not affected.